# Pass parameter from Htmldropdownlistfor to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model passed from controller to view in my asp.net mvc5 website. Then I show the dropdownlist using the model and I want to pass an id back when submitting the form. Here is my model :

```
public class SiteDirectionModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the model, I use a `List<SiteDirectionModel>` to which I add new instances of each item I need. I fill up both these lists and then pass my model to the view.

```
@model List<SiteDirectionModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSiteRF", "Create", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.name,new SelectList(Model.name,"Sites"));
    <input type="button" value="Selectionner" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

Then how to retrieve the ids for each `name` ? And how to pass it as a parameter to my controller? Such that I would have :

```
public ActionResult GetSiteRF(int id)
{
    int newId = id;
    //Call method to searchId ...
    return View("CreateADUser");
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly your model is not looking good.

Comment: `DropDownListFor()` binds to, and posts back a single value, not a collection of values. And you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`. And your parameter is named `id` but you do not have a form control with `name="id"`

Comment: And what do you mean the ids for each `name`?  (name is a `string` and it does not have an id)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use same variable for `DropDownListFor` target & list source together - use a `string` as the target instead. And you have `int id` as action argument but seems referenced to a `List<int>`.

Comment: Ok I have edited my model, now only string and int and then use a `List<SiteDirectionModel>`. Yes it's not coherent what I wrote, tough day ...

Comment: Now this is broken since `Model.name` is not a `List<string>` anymore: `new SelectList(Model.name,"Sites")`.

Comment: Yes, so I have to change my model to List<SiteDirectionModel> right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given how to bind and get value from dropdown. Please use your own BL in this.

Your model should be like this.

```
public class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SiteDirectionModel
{
    public SelectList MyDropDown { get; set; }

    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

You BL should be like this.

```
public List<Something> GetListofSomething()
{
    //your logic.

}
```

Your Get method should be like this.

```
 public ActionResult MyGetMethod()
    {
        SiteDirectionModel model = new SiteDirectionModel();
        model.MyDropDown = new SelectList(GetListofSomething(), "key_field_name", "value_field_name", "default_value");
    }
```

Then finally HTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue,Model.MyDropDown)
```